# I (student) was encouraged to use SYSDBA and I broke my Oracle database. How do I fix it?

Tags: oracle, sysdba

It all started when I tried to run catqm.sql as SYSDBA yesterday:

```
SQL> @?/rdbms/admin/catqm.sql xdb XML_DATA TEMP NO
```

Afterwards, I'd get this error whenever trying to execute DDL:

> ORA-04098: trigger 'SYS.XDB_PI_TRIG' is invalid and failed
> re-validation

After troubleshooting for a while, now I get this error whenever trying to execute DDL:

> Error report - ORA-04098: trigger 'SYS.XDB_INSTALLATION_TRIGGER' is
> invalid and failed re-validation
> 04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
> *Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
> found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
> failed for the trigger.
> *Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
> disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.

I've been troubleshooting for a while, but have only made things worse. This is quite pressing, so any help is appreciated. This stuff is mostly over my head if it wasn't obvious, so talk to me like the idiot that I am =)

I'm guessing I can't just rollback everything from the last 2 days...

Comment: Probably you just need to run the necessary other catalog scripts too. Can't tell you which ones from memory, but duckduckgo.com is your friend.